# Custom Validation in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation

I want custom validation , if my status is Reject then only client able to put integer value in Qty Rejected textbox withing the rang 1 to 10000000.
how will be my CustomValidator1_ServerValidate() method??

[image]

Here is my code for status and Qty Reject:

```
<tr> 
                    <td width="30%">
                        <b>Status:</b> 
                    </td>


                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="lAccept" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="102px">
                            <asp:ListItem>Accept</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Reject</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td width="30%">
                        <b>Qty Rejected:</b> 
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="lRejectedQty" runat="server" CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
                            ErrorMessage="Only interger between 1 to 10000000 " ondisposed="Page_Load" 
                            oninit="Page_Load" onservervalidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
                    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use jquery in your case:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#lRejectedQty').change(function(){
        var txt_value = ParseInt(document.getElementById('lRejectedQty').value);
        var ddl_value = document.getElementById('lAccept').value;
        if(ddl_value == 'Reject'){
            if (txt_value < 1 || txt_value > 10000000){
                document.getElementById('lRejectedQty').focus();
                document.getElementById('some_label_to_display_error_message').value = 'Wrong value';
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps